# How to use IFS with multiple delimiters?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Data in the log file goes like this

```
username - yyyy-mm-dd, HH:MM:SS
```

Now how to seperate username, date and time?

I tried using.

```
while IFS=" - |, " read G1 G2 G3
```

But this considers the hyphen between the date.. any idea?

EDIT:
I actually found a method .....

I used

```
while IFS="-""," read G1 G2 G3 G4
```

And G1 was the username , G2 was - G3 was date and G4 was the time..

I couldn't understand how this works.. but it worked

Thanks

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stack

Comment: You are trying to use it with multiple **multi-character** delimiters. That just won't work. In this particular case you can read them into 4 variables without changing IFS, discard the second, and remove the comma from the third afterwards.

Comment: What you think has worked for you is not at all a solution, `IFS` splits on single character only.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this script in `bash`:

```sh
while IFS= read -r && read G1 G2 G3 <<< "${REPLY//[,-]/}"; do
   echo "[$G1][$G2][$G3]"
done < file.log
```

**Output:**

```sh
[username][yyyymmdd][HH:MM:SS]
```

Here we are reading full line in internal `REPLY` variable first then we use another `read` to get values in 3 variables after cleaning up `$REPLY` by removing `-` and `,` upfront.

Comment: @Jagan: Wondering if this worked out for you

Answer (score 1):

> How to use IFS with multiple delimiters?

It is possible to use IFS with multiple *single character* delimiters. Any character *in the set* in IFS is considered a delimiter. The `IFS=" - |, "` is equal to `IFS=" -|,"` - repeated characters are ignored.

It's not possible to use IFS splitting with any multi-character delimiters.

> any idea?

Use another tool and do the splitting yourself. You could match the line with regex with bash `[[ =~` matching or in `sed` or use `awk` to parse the line or use other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a dummy variable to hold the dash `-` and do a [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to remove the trailing comma `,` e.g. `"${date%,}"`

```
while read -r username _ date time; do
   echo "$username" "${date%,}" "$time"
done < log.txt
```